# Navbar moves to the right on menu dropdown

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse" style="vertical-align: center;">
    <a id="navimg" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/img.png" height="35px" style="margin-top: 3px;"></a>
    <button style="margin-right: -20px;" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <img src="navtog.png" style="margin-right:-28px;margin-top: -4px;" width="30px" height="30px"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><b>Dashboard</b></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="donate.html">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="protect.html">Protect</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

When I click the navbar on mobile, the whole thing shifts to the right.

I don't think there is any css relevant to this problem.
Please ignore the fact that there is an image above the menu icon.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, add more relevant code to your question. Thanks

Comment: Im not sure what would be relevent. @JesperMartinez

Answer (score 0):

if i understood what you want to do you have to use two different div for the navbar and it's content like that:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse" style="vertical-align: center;">
  <a id="navimg" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/img.png" height="35px" style="margin-top: 3px;"></a>
  <button style="margin-right: -20px;" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <img src="navtog.png" style="margin-right:-28px;margin-top: -4px;" width="30px" height="30px"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="protect.html">Protect</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it will help